# Fiddler https error: "because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Tags: ssl, https, fiddler

I am trying to monitor https traffic with Fiddler, using current newest version:2.4.4.5

I've successfully set up https, certificates and I can see the full https encrypted traffic for example browsing my bank's web site.

...however...

When I trying to monitor an other server I got this error message in the response window:

"Failed to secure existing connection for 77.87.178.160. A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

For full Fiddler window see:

[image]

The client is not a in this case browser, but a custom client program, which communicates with its own server.

My question: Is this exception misleading and in reality some other error prevents the secure channel to set up? 
...or...
We have still chance to monitor this https communication?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 14):

What is the client program?

This error typically indicates that that client application is only offering certain HTTPS ciphers, and those ciphers are not supported by Fiddler.

However, in this case, the specific problem here is almost certainly this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/08/aes-is-not-a-valid-cipher-for-sslv3.aspx

The client is trying to use AES with SSLv3, but that isn't one of the valid ciphers for SSL3. As a consequence, the connection fails.

You *might* be able to workaround this by clicking Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll down to the Main() function and add the following line within the function:

```
  CONFIG.oAcceptedServerHTTPSProtocols = 
    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3;
```

Please let me know if this works.

**NOTE** Current versions of Fiddler offer a UI link for this: Look at the lis of enabled protocols on the HTTPS tab.

Comment: Eric, many thanks for your support. Unfortunately this gives me "Variable 'SslProtocols' has not been declared"

Comment: I solved the compile error using System.Security.Authentication namespace. Now I got 0 length response and this error message:

"fiddler.network.https> Failed to secure existing connection for 77.87.178.129. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)" 
Interestingly after commenting out this line now gives the same.

Comment: Try changing the line to *only* Ssl3 (answer updated above). I can successfully connect to the target server from here with that configuration.

Comment: This worked for me. Many thanks as I was banging my head to solve this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Unbelievably this issue is still present some 6 years later.
Just installed the latest version of Fiddle (v5.0.20194.41348), and sure enough on Win7 using Chrome or IE it keeps failing with the dreaded error:

"fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to google.com (for #1) failed. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

After some hours of testing, I found a middle ground solution which seems to work with virtually all websites.  The aim was to get the highest possible security with no errors in the log.  Without needing to add any code, simply changing this line under Tools > Options > HTTPS > Protocols is what worked for me (just copy and paste it):

```
<client>;ssl3;tls1.1;tls1.2
```

Basically removed the ssl2 and tls1.0 protocols which leaves us with some pretty decent security and no errors so far.  Having spent hours of frustration with this error, hope someone out there might find this useful, and a big thanks to EricLaw who discovered the root of the problem.

Comment: SSL3 has been deprecated for years and not considered secure, if security is your aim I'd remove it from the list as well.  In particular it is susceptible to the POODLE and BEAST vulnerabilities.  TLS 1.1 is, I believe, going to be deprecated soon as well.

Comment: Thanks for that info, however in my case I was just looking for a way to make it work for testing purposes only. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I too have seen this error when working outside of fiddler and it was connected with AuthenticateAsServer but only went wrong when using IE10 and not Chrome as the browser.

Odd thing is that it did not break all the time for IE10 using SslProtocols.Tls for the protocol so I will add a bit of code to switch the protocol if one fails

The protocol that can be used also seems to change on if you are using a proxy server like Fiddler or using an invisible server by hijacking the DNS via the hosts file to divert traffic to the server